# See network routes for azure app service on windows

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-virtual-network

Is there a way of seeing which route a outbound request from my app is taking on a windows azure app service.

I want to prove if my requests are routing through the attached vnet or not, it doesn't appear from the console any of the following work:

```
curl https://ifconfig.me/ip

Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing https://ifconfig.me/ip
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your question.

Have you set WEBSITE_VNET_ROUTE_ALL to 1, which ensures all outbound traffic is routed to your VNET? If so, you should be able to look at the clients to see what IP address is being used for the request. Outbound traffic that is being routed via your VNET will be received using your VNET address space.

Outbound traffic that is not using your VNET will be sent via one of the outbound IP addresses, which you can see in the properties blade of your web app in the Azure portal.

More information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet#how-regional-vnet-integration-works).

Due to the sandboxed nature of web apps, most CMD cmdlets do not work.

Comment: thanks - yes, I'm aware I can do that, what I'm trying to do is roll out our vnet integration slowly so would like to rollout the vnet but keep traffic routing out the app service and switch over app by app, having some diagnostics to prove traffic without looking from the outside would give confidence.